# Node Javascript class ReferenceError: X is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following class:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const ConnectionDetails = require("./ConnectionDetails").ConnectionDetails;
const Recipe = require("./recipe").Recipe;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

class MongoDriver{

    async #getClient(uriString){
        const client = new MongoClient(uriString);
        await client.connect();
        return client;
    }

    #getDatabase(client, dbString){
        const db = client.db(dbString);
        return db;
    }

    #getCollection(client, collectionString){
        return client.collection(collectionString)
    }
    
    static async addObject(object, connectionDetails){
        if(!connectionDetails instanceof ConnectionDetails){
            throw "connetionDetails must be of type ConnectionDetails but is " + typeof(connectionDetails);
        }

        if(!object instanceof Recipe){
            throw "object must be of type Recipe but is " + typeof(object);
        }
    
        const mongoClient = getClient(connectionDetails.getUri());
        const database = getDatabase(client, connectionDetails.getDatabase());
        const collection = getCollection(client, connectionDetails.getCollection());
        return await collection.insertOne(object)

    }

  }

  module.exports.MongoDriver = MongoDriver;
```

And when I call the addObject static method I'm getting the following error: ReferenceError: getClient is not defined

Why am I getting an undefined error when the function is defined in my class?

Comment: Try with `this.getClient(...`

Comment: Well there is no variable `getClient`. There is a `this.#getClient` private method that you could call.

Comment: Also change module.exports.MongoDriver = MongoDriver; to module.exports = MongoDriver;.

Comment: Really this should not be a `class` at all. There's no state, you never use an instance for anything (it would be empty). Export an `async function addObject`, and make those helper "methods" to local functions in the module.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting an undefined error when the function is defined in my class?

That's the problem - you defined a class method, not a function. It would have to be called as `this.#getClient` (if it was `static` as well).

Really this should not be a `class` at all. There's no state, you never use an instance for anything (it would be empty). Export an `async function addObject`, and make those helper "methods" to local functions in the module:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const ConnectionDetails = require("./ConnectionDetails").ConnectionDetails;
const Recipe = require("./recipe").Recipe;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

async function getClient(uriString){
    const client = new MongoClient(uriString);
    await client.connect();
    return client;
}

function getDatabase(client, dbString){
    const db = client.db(dbString);
    return db;
}

function getCollection(client, collectionString){
    return client.collection(collectionString)
}

exports.addObject = async function (object, connectionDetails){
    if(!connectionDetails instanceof ConnectionDetails){
        throw "connetionDetails must be of type ConnectionDetails but is " + typeof(connectionDetails);
    }

    if(!object instanceof Recipe){
        throw "object must be of type Recipe but is " + typeof(object);
    }

    const mongoClient = getClient(connectionDetails.getUri());
    const database = getDatabase(client, connectionDetails.getDatabase());
    const collection = getCollection(client, connectionDetails.getCollection());
    return await collection.insertOne(object);
}
```